# How to Display records in div table using AngularJs Like 1-10 out of 100,11-20 out of 100

Tags: html, angularjs

Here i'm new for AngularJs can you please helpme how to show records Like 1-10 out of 100 if I click on next paging 11-20 out of 100.soo o to countinuous

```
<b style="color:red">Items Search is :  {{TotalRec.length}}</b>  
 <b> Toal Records Available {{GetDb.length}}</b>
         <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
            <tr>
               <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                </tr>
            <tr dir-paginate="ee in GetDb|orderBy:sortKey:reverse|filter:search|itemsPerPage:2|filter:query as TotalRec">         
                <td>{{ee.id}}</td>
                <td>{{ee.Name}}</td>
               </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example :
https://github.com/rahil471/search-sort-and-pagination-angularjs

Comment: Did you look at the code?
In index.html, there is one piece of code 
`<dir-pagination-controls
     max-size="5"
     direction-links="true"
     boundary-links="true" >
    </dir-pagination-controls>`
<br>
It has `<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/dirPagination.js"></script>` included in index.html

Comment: Upesh sir i nedd to show 1-10 records when i click on second page its shows me 11-20 if 3rd select 21-30 sooo on to move